# How do I use the Messaging app with an account different from my primary Microsoft account?

Tags: windows-8, windows-live-messenger

I set up this computer with a Local account.

I have linked it to my 'primary' Microsoft account - which is used in the Mail and Store apps. There are no other accounts linked at this time.

I wish to use the Messaging app with a *different* Microsoft account. However, `Add an account` only lets me add a Facebook account! I don't want to remove or change my primary Microsoft account, since I do not wish to use the Messaging account with any other services.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't. Why would you want to do that anyway?

Comment: Because I have multiple Microsoft Accounts. I have one I need to use for Messaging. I have one I would like to use for email and Windows in general. Why *shouldn't* I be able to do that? I have three Google accounts, and have never had a problem switching between them on my phone. I need to keep some things separate, so it's not possible to combine the accounts. Think of it as a work/personal thing.

Comment: In that case I can just suggest you to install an alternate messenger like pidgin.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I ended up going with IM+, for the Modern UI snap (and notifications).

Answer (score 1):

The IM+ app (free on the Windows Store) allows multiple Microsoft accounts, amongst others, and is not linked to existing accounts on the system in any way. It works well as an alternative to the built-in Messaging app, and provides Modern UI style notifications.